# freedom of movement vs move freely

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Question:
Some people believe that professionals, such as doctors and engineers, should be required to work in the country where they did their training. Others believe they should be free to **work in another country** if they wish. Discuss both these views and give your own opinion.

My answer:

> It is best to allow gifted members of society to **move freely** because
> they could reach their full potential when they feel happy and
> fulfilled at work.

An American freelancer I hired changed my sentence to:

> It is best to grant freedom of **movement** to societies' gifted
> because they will reach their full potential when they feel happy and
> fulfilled at work.

Is the freelancer's use of "movement" reflect "work in another" in the question?

Comment: Freedom of movement has a more technical ring to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you be more specific and use less technical language to explain? I don't understand "has a more technical ring".

Comment: It sounds more formal would be a different way of putting it.